# Go: install drive v2 package cmd/cgo error

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get the google drive package for go, but using the below always throws the error. Should I be installing it manually?

```
./go get code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/drive/v2
load cmd/cgo: package cmd/cgo: no Go source files in .../google_appengine/goroot/src/cmd/cgo
```

Answer (score 0):

The package seems to be broken. The basename of its import path (`v2`) doesn't match the package name found there (`drive`).

I'm not sure but I guess maybe some script which generates something is broken. I suggest to ask the committer at golang-nuts

Comment: `go get code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/drive/v2` worked for me.

Comment: @peterSO: That's strange. I tried it before posting the answer and it failed with 1.1rc3. Also, it looks like it shouldn't work - the package and directory names do not match. I must be missing something.

Comment: I am using `go version go1.1rc3 linux/amd64` installed from source. `$ go get -v code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/drive/v2`;
`code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client (download)`;
`code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/googleapi`;
`code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/drive/v2`;
`$`.

Comment: @peterSO: Now I'm at work where I have 1.1rc2 and it works okay. Will try to recheck at home again w/ rc3. I may have / probably had screwed something.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have the Go App Engine SDK, which doesn't include `cgo`, in your `$PATH`.